# Apigee Cache getting refreshed when accessed

Tags: caching, apigee

Say, I set an entry on the Apigee through PopulateCache policy, with an expiration of 3600 seconds, with a key. When I perform a LookUp of the cache with a key, does it refresh the expiry time for the individual entry, or does it still stick to the original duration.

Ex: An Entry is cached for 3000 seconds and now I perform a LookUp. Does it get reset to 3600 seconds again, or does it stay at 3000 seconds only?

Thanks.

Comment: The Apigee docs don't list any entries for `PopulateCache`. Can you paste the relevant sections from your code? Which language are you using? What platform?

Comment: @MaxLeske You can find information on `PopulateCache` and `LookupCache` (with policy examples) here: http://apigee.com/docs/gateway-services/content/optimize-performance-using-cache

Comment: Well that search function sucks... :) The only thing I was able to find is this entry from the docs http://apigee.com/docs/gateway-services/content/reduce-latency-using-responsecache. It sounds to me like the timeout is absolute (no reset on hit) but it's not clear at all. Unfortunately I don't know Apigee at all, so can't really help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing a cached value using a `LookupCache` policy will **not** refresh its expiry TTL.
If it looks like this is happening, you should ensure the `PopulateCache` policy has an appropriate condition. It sounds like you could be setting ("populating") the same value to the cache on every request and therefore never allowing it to expire.

```
<Step>
    <Condition>lookupcache.my-cache-lookup-policy.cachehit == "false"</Condition>
    <Name>my-populate-cache-policy</Name>
</Step>
```

ie. only populate the cache if the cache lookup missed

Comment: I suspected as much, just wanted a confirmation. I was able to confirm the same behavior, in one of my tests, as well. The TTL does not reset every request. It is absolute as mentioned, earlier.

Answer (score 0):

​It was something to do with environment. Once I undeployed the code and redeployed it, things started working fine.

Golden rule of computing :-)
Thanks.